# Number of ways to write 1 as sum of unit fractions

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, integer-partitions

For an integer $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f(n)$ be the number of ways to write 1 as a sum of exactly $n$ unit fractions. For example:

1. $f(1) = 1$ since there is only one way to write 1 as a sum of a single element.
2. $f(2) = 1$, since $1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$, and we can't sum up exactly two unit fraction to get 1.
3. (Not sure about this one actually) $f(3) = 3$, since $1 = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}$, $1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}$  and $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6}$ (perhaps there are more ways that I didn't think about).

Is there a way to estimate $f(n)$?

Comment: See [OEIS A002966](https://oeis.org/A002966).

Comment: Thanks. I will accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To add a little bit to BillyJoe's [A002966](https://oeis.org/A002966) citation, there is not much known about $f(n)$.  Only 8 values have been computed, and the values grow very quickly.  Your $f(3) = 3$ is correct.  Then it's

| n | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f(n) | 14 | 147 | 3462 | 294,314 | 159,330,691 |

In Matthew Crawford's master's thesis linked in the OEIS entry, he makes two estimates for $f(9)$ (which he calls EFO(9)), $8.5 \times 10^{12}$ and $3.0 \times 10^{12}$.